# Ignore abnormal characters when reading file in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, servlets, utf-8

I'm using a servlet to parse a log file and sends the data as json to a jsp page. The log file contains characters that JSON.parse() won't handle. An example of strange characters is "»7í¿7í∏h". I also know that my json format is correct.

I've tried reading/writing the file using utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859-1 and a few more but to no avail. Now I'm looking at finding the strange characters (which are very probably not needed) and ignoring them while reading the file in java.

Is there some way (perhaps in the servlet) I can find characters that json.parse() won't be able to parse?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: What's creating the log file? Is it possible that it's not just a plain text file - perhaps it's a binary file and these are actually headers for individual log entries (e.g. saying the size of the entry)?

Comment: Ha, it works! thanks for the advice. I changed json parser from the standard json.parse() to [json_parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and it works flawlessly :) Jon, I wasn't sure how the files were created. They are plain text though and the abnormal characaters were only on perhaps 2-3 rows out of several thousand. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Dennis S: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change json parser from the standard json.parse() to [json_parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).